# Any way to read file path of imported project in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, directory, path

I have imported a project into my workspace from another folder path lets say `E:/importedProject`.

My workspace path is: `E:/worspace/project/`

I would like to read the path of my imported project when I am on the workspace project.

I have tried:

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IPath path = workspace.getRoot().getLocation(); //which gets the workspace path
```

and also

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

but they are not referring to the imported project's real path that is located..

Any idea?

Comment: `workspace.getRoot().getProject("<project name>").getLocation();` - You missed [`getProject​(String name)`](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IWorkspaceRoot.html#getProject(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed [`getProject​(String name)`](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IWorkspaceRoot.html#getProject(java.lang.String)):

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IPath path = workspace.getRoot().getProject("<project name>").getLocation();
```